# Python 3.3.2 beautifulsoup4 installation failure

Tags: linux, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

Trying to install beautifulsoup4-4.1.3 with python 3.3.2 -

```
 $ sudo /usr/bin/Python-3.3.2/python ./setup.py install
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    running install_lib
    byte-compiling /opt/python3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/bs4/element.py to element.cpython-33.pyc
      File "/opt/python3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/bs4/element.py", line 1200
        print 'Running CSS selector "%s"' % selector
                                        ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax

    byte-compiling /opt/python3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/bs4/tests/test_html5lib.py to test_html5lib.cpython-33.pyc
      File "/opt/python3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/bs4/tests/test_html5lib.py", line 8
        except ImportError, e:
                          ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax

    byte-compiling /opt/python3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/bs4/tests/test_lxml.py to test_lxml.cpython-33.pyc
      File "/opt/python3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/bs4/tests/test_lxml.py", line 11
        except ImportError, e:
                          ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax

    byte-compiling /opt/python3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/bs4/tests/test_soup.py to test_soup.cpython-33.pyc
      File "/opt/python3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/bs4/tests/test_soup.py", line 28
        except ImportError, e:
                          ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax

    byte-compiling /opt/python3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/bs4/__init__.py to __init__.cpython-33.pyc
      File "/opt/python3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/bs4/__init__.py", line 365
        print soup.prettify()
                 ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax

    byte-compiling /opt/python3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/bs4/builder/_htmlparser.py to _htmlparser.cpython-33.pyc
      File "/opt/python3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/bs4/builder/_htmlparser.py", line 68
        except (ValueError, OverflowError), e:
                                          ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax

    running install_egg_info
    Removing /opt/python3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/beautifulsoup4-4.1.3-py3.3.egg-info
    Writing /opt/python3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/beautifulsoup4-4.1.3-py3.3.egg-info
```

Comment: I had no problems installing [4.2.1](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/download/4.2/) with Python 3.3.

Comment: It looks like something goes wrong with the `from distutils.command.build_py import build_py_2to3 as build_py` line in your case. I'd use `pip` or `easy_install` in any case to install packages like these.

Comment: pip use python2.6 I can't seem to find how to use pip to python3 - help is much appreciated!

Comment: `pip` is installed *per* python installation, and usually includes a `pip-version` link as well; try `pip-3.3`.